# Load map after clicking ajax request from marker of Google Map

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, google-maps

Hi I'm encountering a problem regarding creating a new map upon clicking the marker. So here is the flow that I want:

1. Display default google map with markers that I included - I'm okay with this
2. Upon clicking of marker I'll create a new map which the markers will be removed then I'll put an overlay image.

So the problem is whenever I click the marker the new map doesn't appear. Here is my code

**Controller**

```
public function index()
{

    $config = array();

    $config['center']      = '**.*******, **.*******';
    $config['zoom']        = '6';
    $config['map_height']  = "500px";


    $this->googlemaps->initialize($config);

    $marker = array();
    $marker['position']     = "*********";
    $marker['onclick']      = "
                                $.ajax({  
                                url: 'Welcome/new_map',  
                                success: function(data) {  
                                    $('#v_map').html(data);
                                }  
                            }); 
                            ";

    $marker['animation']    = 'DROP';
    $this->googlemaps->add_marker($marker);

    $marker = array();
    $marker['position']     = "*********";
    $this->googlemaps->add_marker($marker);

    $data['map'] = $this->googlemaps->create_map();

    $this->load->view('welcome_message', $data);
}

public function new_map(){

    $config = array();

    $config['center']      = '**.*******, **.*******';
    $config['zoom']        = '6';
    $config['map_height']  = "500px";


    $this->googlemaps->initialize($config);

    $marker = array();
    $marker['position']     = "*********";
    $marker['onclick']      = "
                                $.ajax({  
                                url: 'Welcome/new_map',  
                                success: function(data) {  
                                    $('#v_map').html(data);
                                }  
                            }); 
                            ";

    $marker['animation']    = 'DROP';
    $this->googlemaps->add_marker($marker);

    $marker = array();
    $marker['position']     = "*********";
    $this->googlemaps->add_marker($marker);

    $data['map'] = $this->googlemaps->create_map();

    $this->load->view('map_template', $data);
}
```

**View**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <?php echo $map['js']; ?>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
</head>
<body>
  <div id = "v_map">
    <?php echo $map['html']; ?>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**map_template**

```
<?php echo $map['html']; ?>
```

I'm currently trying to fix that the new map will appear before proceeding with the overlay part.

PS. I'm using Biostall's library of Google maps for Codeigniter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `public function new_map(){`, you are trying to get ajax response, so you need

From

```
  $this->load->view('map_template', $data);
```

To

```
 echo $this->load->view('map_template', $data, TRUE);
```

> Ref: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html
>
> Returning views as data
>
> There is a third optional parameter lets you change the behavior of
>   the method so that it returns data as a string rather than sending it
>   to your browser. This can be useful if you want to process the data in
>   some way. If you set the parameter to TRUE (boolean) it will return
>   data.

**Here is working controller, on CI 2.2.6, if you are on new version of codeigniter than you need to take care of filename conventions (Ucfirst-like manner):**

Here is Ref : https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Welcome extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('googlemaps');
        $this->load->helper('url');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $config = array();
        $config['center'] = '37.4419, -122.1419';
        $config['zoom'] = 'auto';
        $config['map_height'] = "500px";
        $this->googlemaps->initialize($config);

        $url = site_url('welcome/new_map');
        $marker = array();
        $marker['position'] = "*********";
        $marker['onclick'] = " 
                                $.ajax({  
                                url: '$url',
                                success: function(data) {  
                                    $('#v_map').html(data);
                                    initialize_map();
                                }
                            }); 
                            ";
        $marker['animation'] = 'DROP';
        $this->googlemaps->add_marker($marker);
        $marker = array();
        $marker['position'] = "*********";
        $this->googlemaps->add_marker($marker);

        $data['map'] = $this->googlemaps->create_map();

        $this->load->view('map', $data);
    }

    public function new_map()
    {
        // map config
        $config = array();
        $config['center'] = '37.4419, -122.1419';
        $config['zoom'] = 'auto';
        $config['map_height'] = "500px";

        // no need of including script tag again
        $config['maps_loaded'] = 1;

        $this->googlemaps->initialize($config);

        // overlay image
        $groundOverlay = array();
        $groundOverlay['image'] = 'http://maps.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logos/maps_logo.gif';
        $groundOverlay['positionSW'] = '40.712216,-74.22655';
        $groundOverlay['positionNE'] = '40.773941,-74.12544';
        $this->googlemaps->add_ground_overlay($groundOverlay);

        // create map
        $data = $this->googlemaps->create_map();

         // ajax response
        echo $data['html'] . $data['js'];

        // Since there is no need of loading, view just used echo
    }
}

/* End of file welcome.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/welcome.php */
```

**View File : map.php**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
  <?php echo $map['js']; ?> 
</head>
<body>
  <div id = "v_map">
    <?php echo $map['html']; ?>
  </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

**Library:**

Source : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BIOSTALL/CodeIgniter-Google-Maps-V3-API-Library/master/application/libraries/Googlemaps.php

So what all I have, in my application folder :

```
$ pwd
/var/www/html/ci/application

.
├── controllers
│   ├── index.html
│   └── welcome.php
├── libraries
│   ├── Googlemaps.php
│   └── index.html
└── views
    ├── index.html
    ├── map.php
    └── welcome_message.php
```

**Access:**

```
http://127.0.0.1/ci/index.php/welcome
```

**And click on marker, you will get below overlay image after clicking marker**

[image]

Overlay image:
[image]

Comment: I've added the `initialize_map();` and echo the ajax response to get the same result. Thanks.